# Postgresql stops working for remote clients after some time

Tags: postgresql

First of all, sorry if there is a similar question. I haven't found anyone that solves my problem.

I have 3 computers set in a local network. Computer 1 is the master computer who has the database in local and runs the desktop application I'm working with. Computer 2 and Computer 3 run the same desktop application, and they connect to the database in Computer 1.
Postgresql is set to accept connections, the other parameters of the postgresql configuration are the default ones.

Everything seems to work fine, but after some hours have passed, Computer 2 and 3 cannot connect to Computer 1. However, Computer 1 can still work fine with the database.

```
2014-XX-XX 13:33:33 CET FATAL: connection to client lost
2014-XX-XX 13:33:33 CET LOG: cannot send data to client. No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

If I reboot Computer 2 and 3, everything works again, but I can't keep rebooting the computers many times every day.

Does anyone knows where the problem lies? For what I've searched maybe is a memory issue, but I'm no database expert and I'm not sure what parameters of the postgresql configuration I have to modify.

Thanks!

Comment: i think that is not the right place for your problem, perhaps [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) ?

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that the issue here is a connection tracking firewall,r router or NAT device that's expiring connection tracking entries.

Enable TCP keepalives, either [server-side](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html), or if your client supports it, client-side.